# Image use in Python

Tags: python, gif

I need to display a `.gif` file in my source code. The only thing I've been able to find instruction wise is to use:

`image = Image(Point(x,y), "filename.gif")`

I keep getting an error that says:

`couldn't open "filename.gif": no such file or directory`

I'm not sure what to do?

I think maybe I have the files I'm trying to access in a place that python can't access.

I'm using graphics, and I did import it, and this is what the graphics module reference says to do also, so I don't think I'm putting it in wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the program in the same folder where the 'filename.gif' is?

Comment: @TuukkaX No, I'm not sure. And I'm not sure how to check. This is for a class, and I just put everything I need in the file for that class, saved .py files, and the .gif and I can open the .py files from that folder fine. It's the same folder why my graphics library is saved.

Comment: Are you running the program from an IDE or straight from the executable file?

Comment: I'm running it from Wing IDE.

Comment: If you want that code to work when running from IDE, you must move the 'filename.gif' file to the same folder where your program is being ran from.  Also check out the answer that @Anil_M provided, might be that case too.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`image = Image.open(Point(x,y), "filename.gif")`

Looks like you may be missing `open` in `Image.open`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure its in the same folder as your python script. If that doesn't work, then set up a path like user Adam Smith did.

Answer (score -1):

You should specify the absolute path to the file.

```
image = Image(Point(x, y), "C:/my/path/to/the/filename.gif")
```